# CakePHP 2.6 Validation Rule isUnique per belongsTo Parent

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I'm trying to figure out how to build a validation rule, and the simplest example I can give would be a class signup with students emails.  I want each class to be able to have unique student emails signup, but I also want students to be able to sign up with the same email for multiple classes.

Class hasMany Students  (id, name, limit)

Student belongsTo Class   (id, email, class_id)

Example Scenario:

Class A, has student signup: abc@email.edu  (If abc@email.edu signed up again for this class, it would not allow.)

Class B, could have student signup: abc@email.edu again since it's a different class.

So is there a way to use isUnique in combination with another rule, or is this a custom validator situation? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have to answer a different question here, because your model association doesn't make sense.

If any one Student can take multiple classes and a Class can have multiple students, then your association needs to be **hasAndBelongsToMany**. Your `students` table, then, would not have a `class_id`. You would instead set up a join table, `classes_students`, which would have a `class_id` and `student_id`.

Then you could add a validation rule on the join table to make sure no student is taking the same class twice. See this [Making HABTM relationships unique in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396062/making-habtm-relationships-unique-in-cakephp) question.

Comment: Got it, I'll try this model association.  Thanks!